# cannot navigate with Serializable object from activity to another in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, navigation

i am trying to navigate from activity to another and pass object from entity table i have by using  Serializable :

```
@Entity(tableName = "client")
data class ClientEntity(........) : Serializable 
{
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
var id : Int? = null}
```

the navigate will happen when the button click

the intent implementation inside the button onClickListener :

```
val clientEntity = ClientEntity(......)
val intent = Intent(this,ProfileActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("clientEntity",clientEntity)
startActivity(intent)
```

so when i try to navigate i get this error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system

i search for this error and all the answers make like what i do also i don't know the reason of error

Comment: Doesn't a class have to implement `Parcelable` in order to be reliably passed around via `Intent`s? Not sure if `Serializable` is sufficient in that case. Don't think so…

Comment: i sow answers with serializable before so i think it's possible

Comment: Maybe, I would read in the official docs…